# Extract year from string and append to dataframe

Tags: r

I have a wine dataset with a column called "title" which contains the title of the wine including its vintage year. Refer sample:

- Pull 2013 Chardonnay (Paso Robles)
- R2 2013 Camp 4 Vineyard Grenache Blanc (Santa Ynez Valley)

I want to extract just the year in the strings i.e. 2013, and not the rest of the number in the string e.g. 2, 4.

I got to this part:

## Extract vintage year from title column

`wine_tidy2$vintage_year <- as.list(str_extract_all(wine_tidy2$title, "[0-9]+"))`

But how do I exclude other numbers that are not part of the year?

I want to append the result to a data frame. With the above code, it adds the resulting list to the data frame, how can I add to the data frame as another column of integer?

Thank you.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract("R2 2013 Camp 4 Vineyard Grenache Blanc (Santa Ynez Valley)", "\\d{4}")`

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @d.b I know that str_extract will extract the first match. Is it possible to tweak this solution so that it will extract a range of year for example from 1935 to 2017?
Or does that involve a new code altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `sub()` or `regexec()` from base by searching for numbers with have 4 digits:

```
string <- c('R2 2013 Camp 4 Vineyard Grenache Blanc', 'Santa Ynez Valley 1999', 'dsdd 2015')
sub("^.*([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", string)
unlist(regmatches(string, regexec("[0-9]{4}", string)))
```

for your case:

```
# create a helper function
yearExtract <- function(string) {
  t <- regmatches(string, regexec("[0-9]{4}", string))
  sapply(t, function(x) {
    if(length(x) > 0){
      return(as.numeric(x))
    } else {
      return(NA)    
    }
  })
}


# create data.frame
title <- c('R2 2013 Camp 4 Vineyard Grenache Blanc', 'Santa Ynez Valley 1999', 'dsdd 15')
distributor <- c('a', 'b', 'd')
wine_tidy2 <- data.frame(title, distributor)

wine_tidy2$vintage_year <- yearExtract(as.character(wine_tidy2$title))
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see that it is not anymore a list but a chr. However, when the wine title has no year in it, it extracts all the title. How do I improve this solution so that it leaves it blank when there is no year stated in the string?

Comment: okay now it convert in to a number and include NA for missing values. if your question is answered mark it as solved and consider to vote up the answer (;